# Finding Structure for Package Editor docked cell

Tags: docked-cell

I'm attempting to modify (overwrite) the docked cell in the package editor to add some "jump to" capability.  It has built in "jump to a function" action menu which is nice, but I'd like to expand on this as not all of my cells are functions.  I have quite a few cells so this would save me time.

I can find the structure of the docked cell in a regular notebook using the following code:

```
CellPrint[DockedCells /. Options@NotebookOpen["you file name here"]]
```

I got this from: [How to see the 'source code' of DockedCells? ALT: How to 'show expression' of DockedCell?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10003/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-dockedcells-alt-how-to-show-expression-of-do/10012#10012)

It works perfectly.  However, it doesn't seem to work for .m files.  Can anyone direct me?

Comment: `CurrentValue[DockedCells]`

Comment: Well that was easy.  : )  Thank you!

Comment: And you can modify it in $InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/MiscExpressions.tr starting with line "PackageToolbar" ->...

Comment: Awesome... you just saved me more time.  Thank you!

Comment: Since your question is only how to get it and change it then I think it may be marked as duplicate of [Can the banner in the Home Edition be removed?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11403/5478).